# Robot Framework - Unable to find filter xpath in Kendo grid and add text

Tags: selenium, xpath, kendo-grid, robotframework

I am attempting to create a Robot Framework Selenium test where I input text into a Kendo grid filter and then check the results. The grid is here:

[image: Kendo Grid example screenshot]

The filter code is here:

```
<thead class="k-grid-header" xpath="1">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rowFilterContainer"></td>
    <td class="rowFilterContainer"></td>
    <td class="rowFilterContainer" data-field="UserId"></td>
    <td class="rowFilterContainer" data-field="CandidateId">
      <input class="rowFilter" data-field="CanddateId" data-type="string" type="text" data- 
      operator="startswith">
    </td>
```

I am attempting to locate and then enter text in the `CandidateId` field using Selenium with an xpath of `"//div[@id='Tab_0']//td[4]//input[1]"` but when I run the test if complains that it cannot find it.

Any help on how to find this field (with a better xpath) and to add the text would be greatly appreciated. I have tried using CSS as well.

[image: rest of HTML]

Comment: Is it possible that this field is generated when you click on it? So first `Click Element   //td[@data-field='CandidateId']` and then `Input Text       //td[@data-field='CandidateId']/input`

Comment: I've never used Kendo Grid. It looks like the sort of thing that might be in an iframe. Is it in an iframe?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The data is there without clicking the actual field

Comment: Can you post a link to the page you are automating, or the full page HTML? Given the obvious `//td/input` XPath isn't working here, there's definitely something else going on with that page. With your current HTML sample, it is very difficult to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: Hi, I have added a screenshot (rest of HTML) link above with the code above

Comment: Is this [Telerik Demo page](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-row) the functionality that is used?

Comment: Yes it looks very similar

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath:

```
//td[@data-field='CandidateId']/input
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(.//thead[@class='k-grid-header']/tr)[2]/td[4]/input[@class='rowFilter']
```

Comment: Element with locator 'candidate_id_filter' not found.

Comment: I mean when you use the above `xpath` what error you get?

Comment: The same issue. Complains it can't find it